# Questions about C++ Core Guideline C.12: Don’t make data members const or references

Tags: c++

[Don’t make data members const or references](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-constref)

[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c312b96fba292071)

```
Example; bad
class bad {
    const int i;    // bad
    string& s;      // bad
    // ...
};
```

> The const and & data members make this class “only-sort-of-copyable” –
> copy-constructible but not copy-assignable.
>
> Note If you need a member to point to something, use a pointer (raw or
> smart, and gsl::not_null if it should not be null) instead of a
> reference.
>
> Enforcement Flag a data member that is const, &, or &&.

I try to apply this guideline to my code but I have some issues with the recommendations.
First, I don't care whether or not the class is copyable or not. Second, I don't want the pointer receiving class(i.e. `class DEFBad`) to modify the passed pointer(i.e. `ABCBad*`).

The following code snippet(i.e. `ABCBad & DEFBad`) is my current design. If my understanding of the `C.12` is correct, then I need to change the code similar to `ABCCore & DEFCore`. However, it doesn't satisfy my design perspective.

```
class ABCBad
{
// ...
};

class DEFBad
{
public:
  DEFBad(const ABCBad& abc) : m_abc(abc) {}
  
private:
  const ABCBad& m_abc;
};

// *************************

class ABCCore
{
// ...
};

class DEFCore
{
public:
  DEFCore(ABCCore* abc_core) : m_abc_core(abc_core) {}
  
private:
  ABCCore* m_abc_core;
};
```

**Question**> Do I misunderstand the `C.12` completely?

Comment: If you don't want `DEF` to be able to modify the `ABC` then use a `const ABC*` member.  Now your class is copyable and copy assignable and you can't modify the variable you are pointing to.  The constructor can take the `ABC` object by lvalue reference if you wan to guarantee you don't get a null pointer.

Comment: `C.12` is a guideline.  Since in this case the class does not need to be copy-able (which means you probably should `= delete` the copy constructor and assignment operator), you can ignore `C.12` and not worry about it.

Comment: When you write, "I don't want the pointer receiving class ... to modify the passed pointer", do you want the class to not modify the pointer *itself* or what the pointer points to?

Comment: @NathanOliver, What is the key problem that I use `const ABCBad& m_abc`?

Comment: @jjramsey, I don't want the DEF to modify ABC. In other words, I don't want to modify the pointer points to.

Comment: `const int*` is not `int* const`. Having a `const` somewhere in the type doesn't mean it's a constant type.

Comment: @q0987 There isn't really a problem with it if you don't care the class is no longer assignable, but if you want assignability then it is a problem.  Most classes are assignable, so preventing that may break others expectations.  This is just a guideline, it doesn't work for every situation, just the "80%".  Personally I would use the pointer so that class is more flexible.  If you dislike working with a pointer, it's only one line of code to fix that in each function, ie: `const ABC& abc_ref = *abc_pointer;`

Comment: @NathanOliver, I will correct the code and start to use `const ABC*`. Thank you!

Comment: Prior to c++20, one could change const values in a class by calling the delete operator and putting in a new object with placement new. But this didn't really work because compilers may assume that a const in a memory location can never change. Even if it's underlying value did. So `std::launder` was invented to allow reading it. But it doesn't really solve the problem and only provides an indirect way to access the new const data. This limitation no longer applies in c++ 20 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8.3 to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#8

Comment: Also, you can write an assignment operator if you want to make the class assignable. Just a few lines of code. Then you're good to go.

Comment: Here's an example of a 2D matrix implementation where everything is checked for UB and even returns a `constexpr std::array<std::array<int,4>, 3>` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759196/5282154