# Can one make a 2D matrix class where often accessed sizes, rows and cols, are const members and not getter functions?

Tags: c++

I'm continually irritated that matrix dimensions are accessed with getters. Sure one can have public rows and cols but these should be `const` so that users of the Matrix class can't directly modify them. This is a natural way of coding but, because using const members is regarded, apparently incorrectly, as not possible without UB, results in people using non-const fields when they really should be consts that are mutable when needed such as resizing, or assigning.

What I'd like is something that can be used like this:

```
Matrix2D<double> a(2, 3);
int index{};
for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++)
    for (int ii = 0; ii < a.cols; ii++)
        a(i, ii) = index++;
```

but where `a.rows=5;` isn't compilable because it's const. And it would be great if the class can be included in vectors and other containers.

Now comes: Implement C++20's P0784 (More constexpr containers)
https://reviews.llvm.org/D68364?id=222943

It should be doable without casts or UB and can even be done when evaluating const expressions. I believe c++20 has made it doable by providing the functions `std::destroy_at` and `std::construct_at`. I have attached an answer using c++20 that appears to show it is indeed possible, and easily done, to provide const member objects in classes without an undue burden.

So the question is do the new constexpr functions in c++20, which provide the ability to destroy and then construct an object with different consts valid? It certainly appears so and it passes the consexpr lack of UB test.

Comment: It's just not viable. `const` members suck, because they make classes non-assignable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, I know. But you can write your own. Just a few lines of code.

Comment: Write your own what?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat assignment member functions of course

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't remember if there's a legal way to modify them. Probably calling the destructor, then placement-new (on the whole object) is legal; but then you need to jump through hoops to make sure your assignment operator stays exception-safe. I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  It's actually now easy with c++20 and construct_at, destroy_at and they are even labeled `constexpr`  Very cool.  As I said, just a few lines of code.

Comment: Then I don't understand, what's your question? It seems you know how to write such a matrix class?

Comment: It is not valid to assign a new value to a const member. Using destroy-in-place and construct-in-place magic to assign a new value likely invokes undefined behavior, and most certainly will if there are references to that const member cached anywhere (which is more likely because it was const).

What do you have against getters and setters? They're just as fast as member functions -- and with good header hygiene they can be inlined so they're _exactly_ as fast as members. But they're far more versatile.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Yes, I believe I do. I've put together an example but it seems the general idea of const members is considered a non-starter.  I don't believe that's the case any longer but I've lived with it up to now.

Comment: @inetknght I don't like functions to get the info because I'm used to c# properties and it seems nuts that c++ didn't offer a solution. Until now.

Comment: So you're looking for `public const private mutable`?

Comment: @inetknght It seems to be legal since C++20. Compare https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8.3 (C++17) and http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8 (C++20)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but it explicitly calls out that the types need to be non-const. And it also specifically calls out that doing that with const objects is undefined behavior. `Creating a new object within the storage that a const complete object with static, thread, or automatic storage duration occupies, or within the storage that such a const object used to occupy before its lifetime ended, results in undefined behavior.`

Comment: @inetknght The key word here is *complete* const object. The whole class object needs to be const for it to kick in, a mere const member is not enough.

Comment: The complete const object is the object you're trying to change. Whether that's a `const struct Matrix2D<...>` or whether that's a `const int`: both are undefined behavior to do your proposed magic.

Comment: @inetknght I've done the UB constexpr test on complete const objects. It failed as expected. However works fine on objects that contain consts. This appears specifically done for c++20 https://reviews.llvm.org/D68364?id=222943

Comment: @inetknght I found this description of what and why the change in basic.life was made. Prior to c++17 const sub-objects required `std::launder` for access. This was changed in c++20 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0532r0.pdf

Comment: @inetknght *"The complete const object is the object you're trying to change"* Uhm no. "Complete" has a specific meaning: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#def:complete_object

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  your comment about assignment-safe exception handling motivated me to address that in my answer below. I think it works for both assignments and not too ugly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have const properties you can try this :

```cpp
class Matrix {
    public:
        const int rows;
        const int cols;
        
        Matrix(int _rows, int _cols) : rows(_rows), cols(_cols)
        {
            
        }
};
```

The `rows` and `cols` properties of a `Matrix` instance are initialized once in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my pass at using const rows and cols in a 2D matrix. It passes UB tests and can be used in collections like vector w/o weird restrictions. It's a partial implementation. No bounds checking and such but to provide a possible approach to the problem.

matrix2d.h

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <array>

template<class T>
class Matrix2D
{
    std::vector<T> v;
public:
    const size_t rows;
    const size_t cols;
    constexpr Matrix2D(const Matrix2D& m) = default;
    constexpr Matrix2D(Matrix2D&& m) noexcept = default;
    explicit constexpr Matrix2D(size_t a_rows=0, size_t a_cols=0) : v(a_rows* a_cols), rows(a_rows), cols(a_cols) {}
    constexpr Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list) : rows(list.size()), cols((list.begin())->size())
    {
        for (auto& p1 : list)
            for (auto p2 : p1)
                v.push_back(p2);
    }
    constexpr Matrix2D& operator=(const Matrix2D& mat)
    {
        std::vector<T> tmp_v = mat.v;
        std::construct_at(&this->rows, mat.rows);
        std::construct_at(&this->cols, mat.cols);
        this->v.swap(tmp_v);
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr Matrix2D& operator=(Matrix2D&& mat) noexcept
    {
        std::construct_at(&this->rows, mat.rows);
        std::construct_at(&this->cols, mat.cols);
        this->v.swap(mat.v);
        return *this;
    }

    // user methods
    constexpr T* operator[](size_t row) {   // alternate bracket indexing
        return &v[row * cols];
    };
    constexpr T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col)
    {
        return v[row * cols + col];
    }
    constexpr const T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const
    {
        return v[row * cols + col];
    }
    constexpr Matrix2D operator+(Matrix2D const& v1) const
    {
        if (rows != v1.rows || cols != v1.cols) throw std::range_error("cols and rows must be the same");
        Matrix2D ret = *this;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ret.v.size(); i++)
            ret.v[i] += v1.v[i];
        return ret;
    }
    constexpr Matrix2D operator-(Matrix2D const& v1) const
    {
        if (rows != v1.rows || cols != v1.cols) throw std::range_error("cols and rows must be the same");
        Matrix2D ret = *this;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ret.v.size(); i++)
            ret.v[i] -= v1.v[i];
        return ret;
    }
    constexpr Matrix2D operator*(Matrix2D const& v1) const
    {
        if (cols != v1.rows) throw std::range_error("cols of first must == rows of second");
        Matrix2D v2 = v1.transpose();
        Matrix2D ret(rows, v1.cols);
        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            for (size_t col = 0; col < v1.cols; col++)
            {
                T tmp{};
                for (size_t row_col = 0; row_col < cols; row_col++)
                    tmp += this->operator()(row, row_col) * v2(col, row_col);
                ret(row, col) = tmp;
            }
        return ret;
    }
    constexpr Matrix2D transpose() const
    {
        Matrix2D ret(cols, rows);
        for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
                ret(c, r) = this->operator()(r, c);
        return ret;
    }

    // Adds rows to end
    constexpr Matrix2D add_rows(const Matrix2D& new_rows)
    {
        if (cols != new_rows.cols) throw std::range_error("cols cols must match");
        Matrix2D ret = *this;
        std::construct_at(&ret.rows, rows + new_rows.rows);
        ret.v.insert(ret.v.end(), new_rows.v.begin(), new_rows.v.end());
        return ret;
    }

    constexpr Matrix2D add_cols(const Matrix2D& new_cols)
    {
        if (rows != new_cols.rows) throw std::range_error("rows must match");
        Matrix2D ret(rows, cols + new_cols.cols);
        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                ret(row, col) = this->operator()(row, col);
            for (size_t col = cols; col < ret.cols; col++)
                ret(row, col) = new_cols(row, col - cols);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(Matrix2D const& v1) const
    {
        if (rows != v1.rows || cols != v1.cols || v.size() != v1.v.size())
            return false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            if (v[i] != v1.v[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    constexpr bool operator!=(Matrix2D const& v1) const
    {
        return !(*this == v1);
    }

    // friends
    template <size_t a_rows, size_t a_cols>
    friend constexpr auto make_std_array(const Matrix2D& v)
    {
        if (a_rows != v.rows || a_cols != v.cols) throw std::range_error("template cols and rows must be the same");
        std::array<std::array<T, a_cols>, a_rows> ret{};
        for (size_t r = 0; r < a_rows; r++)
            for (size_t c = 0; c < a_cols; c++)
                ret[r][c] = v(r, c);
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix2d.h"

constexpr std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4> foo()
{
    Matrix2D<double> a(2, 3), b;
    Matrix2D d(a);
    int index{};
    for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++)
        for (int ii = 0; ii < a.cols; ii++)
            a(i, ii) = index++;
    b = a + a;

    Matrix2D<int> z1{ {1},{3},{5} };
    z1 = z1.add_cols({{2}, {4}, {6}});
    z1 = z1.add_rows({{7,8}});
    // z1 is now {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}}
    Matrix2D<int> z2{ {1,2,3},{4,5,6} };
    Matrix2D<int> z3 = z1 * z2;     // z3: 4 rows, 3 cols

    // from separate math program product of z1 and z2
    Matrix2D<int> ref{ {9,12,15},{19,26,33},{29,40,51},{39,54,69} };

    // test transpose
    Matrix2D<int> tmp = ref.transpose(); // tmp: now 3 rows, 4 cols
    if (ref == tmp) throw;  // verify not equal
    tmp = tmp.transpose();  // now ref==tmp==z3
    if (ref != tmp || ref != z3) throw;

    // Check using vector of matrixes, verify sort on row size works
    std::vector<Matrix2D<int>> v;
    v.push_back(z1);
    v.push_back(z2);
    v.push_back(z1);
    v.push_back(z2);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto const& m1, auto const& m2) {return m1.rows < m2.rows; });
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
        if (v[i].rows > v[i + 1].rows) throw;

    // return constexpr of 2D std::array
    std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4> array = make_std_array<4,3>(ref); // ref must have 4 rows, 3 cols
    return array;
}


int main()
{
    auto print = [](auto& a) {
        for (auto& x : a)
        {
            for (auto y : x)
                std::cout << y << " ";
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    };

    // run time
    auto zz = foo();
    print(zz);

    // validating no UB in Matrix2D;
    // and creating a nested, std::array initialized at compile time
    //constexpr std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4>  x = foo();
    constexpr std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4>  x = foo(); // compile time
    print(x);
    return 0;
}
```